# How can I display an xmp image file in a window in xlib? (I'm coding in C)

Tags: c, xlib

I am creating Chess in C, and I need to print the board after every move. I have managed to print the board using strings as pieces but I would like to replace the strings with images of actual pieces.

I haven't been able to find a solution for displaying an image in an X11 window.

```
for(i=0;i<8;i++){
for(j=0;j<8;j++){
    if(board[i][j]>0){
        if(board[i][j]==100)
            strcpy(text,"Pawn");
        else if(board[i][j]==300)
            strcpy(text,"Knight");
        else if(board[i][j]==400)
            strcpy(text,"Bishop");
        else if(board[i][j]==500)
            strcpy(text,"Rook");
        else if(board[i][j]==900)
            strcpy(text,"Queen");
        else if(board[i][j]==10000)
            strcpy(text,"King");
XSetForeground(dpy,gc,whiteColor);
XDrawString(dpy,w,gc,j*100+20,i*100+50, text, strlen(text));
```

This snippet displays the white pieces using text in white color.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing XMP file is not supported directly with X11. There is built-in support for `png`, `jpeg` and the older format (pixmap, bitmap, etc). First step will be to convert the XMP into fixed size image (from the code, looks like 20*50).

In general, you want to preload the images (from files):

```
#include <Xm/Xm.h>

 static unsigned char data[] = {
                0x13, 0x00, 0x15, 0x00, 0x93, 0xcd, 0x55, 0xa5, 0x93, 0xc5, 0x00, 0x80,
0x00, 0x60

        } ;
Screen s = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(d) ;
Pixel fg = XWhitePixelOfScreen(s) ;
Pixel bg = XBlackPixelOfScreen(s) ;
// Pixmap king_pm = XmGetPixmap(s, "king.png", fg, bg) ;
// Pixmap queen_pm = XmGetPixmap(s, "queen.png", fg, bg) ;

Pixmap king_pm = XCreatePixmapFromBitmapData(d, RootWindowOfScreen(s), data, 8, 8, fg, bg, 8) ;
```

Then drawing is based on COPYING the pixmap into the display (using the indices as above). For example, to draw the king.

```
   XCopyArea(dpy, king_pm, gc, 0, 0, 20, 50, j*100+20,i*100+50) ;
```

Disclaimer: I do not have a way to test this code. You might need to troubleshoot/fix as needed.

Comment: Hey, so I tried it. First I had to get the header files in my system. Then due to compiler errors, i modified your code to :                                                  
               `Screen *s=DefaultScreenOfDisplay(dpy);
                Pixel fg=XWhitePixelOfScreen(s);
                Pixel bg=XWhitePixelOfScreen(s);
                Pixmap king_pm=XmGetPixmap(s,"/mnt/c/Users/soham/Desktop/DSA_Project/king.png",fg,bg);
                XCopyArea(dpy,king_pm,w,gc,0,0,20,50,120,150);` This gave me error "Couldn't find per display information". Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I've revised code to use different Pixmap creation (Using Xlib function, instead of Motif). Not as flexible, but might do the trick

Comment: Giving me BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) error. Major opcode of failed request:  62 (X_CopyArea)

Comment: Try changing the last parameter (depth) to match the depth of the window used for drawing.

Comment: Okay that worked, It displayed a white square. How do I change data[ ] to display pieces now?

Comment: Using image magick, `convert file.png file.xbm`. It will produce a file that can be #include into your code. You can also edit the file. Note also correction to bg (BlckPixel...)